# error in angular2 ng-include custom directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am new to Angular2. Angular2 didn't provide ng-include directive.
        So I make it custom by help of this plunk link `http://plnkr.co/edit/OjxKE9HWnDInKojuhhk8?p=preview`

In above link externel html file is passed to cusome component.I too want same case..

But I am using Rc5 and angular 2.4.0 version so I make this plunk to according to my configuration .So few difference are take place according to latest angular version

(Difference) is ->directive declaration, ComponentResolver is renamed as
         ComponentFactoryResolver like few things.

So I am getting 2 issues

```
    1) @Input is not working only on plunker (but it's working my local environment)
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IulUb7
        this is error

```
   2) entrycomponents error . Even I added it @NgModule decorator.for this please check this
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0EfFX3?p=preview Here I commented @input.

```
    My Aim is pass external html(view) file to the include directive where I       
 want.just like angular1 include 

I want to use drective like
```

**business.profile.view.html**

```
<h1>This is profile</h1>
 <my-ng-include src="'business.profile.edit.html'"></my-ng-include>
```

**business.common.component.ts**

```
 import {Component, Input, ViewContainerRef, OnInit,OnDestroy, ComponentRef,     

    ViewChild,ComponentFactoryResolver} from "@angular/core";



@Component({
  selector: 'my-ng-include',
  template: `<div #myNgIncludeContent></div>`
})
export class MyNgInclude implements OnInit,OnDestroy  {

  // Private properties
  componentReference: ComponentRef<any>;

  isViewInitialized = false;

//  @Input('src') private templateUrl: any;

  @ViewChild('myNgIncludeContent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  protected myNgIncludeContent: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private ComponentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver ) {
 //   console.log(templateUrl,'templateUrl')
  }

  createContentComponent() {
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-ng-include-content',
      template: `<h1>This is template</h1>`,
      // templateUrl : templateUrl

    })
    class MyNgIncludeContent {}
    return MyNgIncludeContent ;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isViewInitialized = true;
    this.updateComponent(templateUrl);

 }

  updateComponent () {

    var dynamicComponent = this.createContentComponent();
    let factory = this.ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(dynamicComponent);

    this.componentReference  = this.myNgIncludeContent.createComponent(factory);
 }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // If we have a component, make sure we destroy it when we lose our owner
    if (this.componentReference) {
      this.componentReference.destroy();
    }
  }
```

}

@input(src) is commented

Here I am passing one html file to **myNgInclude** component directive.

Please help me to solve , I am struggling it from 2 days
        Thank You

Comment: Please edit your question, right now it really doesn't make any sense. A Plunker link is fine, but point out the errors and relevant code in your question, because right not we do not have any use for the second links, as that only opens a plunker and doesn't point to any error. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you Please check it now . I added some code